# Firestore: Limitation with multiple queries using inequality operators

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

there are three yields that I need to pull about firestore. If I need to explain my query in detail; I should get above a certain date as the language of the item and the number of likes in order.

However, although I tried almost every combination, I could not get over the following error;

**Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, !=, not-in, >, or >=) must be on the same field.
**

Images;

[image: indexes]

[image: query]

[image: error message]

I don't know much about indexes. That's why I'm open to any suggestions.

**Also, I don't know if it will work, but I would like to add it as a note; I need to add the like query only for orderby.**

Answer (score 1):

As detailed in the error message shown in the console, as well as in the Firetore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) "You can perform range (<, <=, >, >=) or not equals (!=) comparisons **only on a single field**". In your case you have a >= and a != clauses on two different fields.

There isn't any solution as this is a Firestore limitation (and adapting the indexes will not change the situation).

You can try to adapt your data model to circumvent the limitation but I don't think there is any easy data model adaptation possible in your case.

Non exhaustive list of possible (but not ideal) approaches:

- Have a subcollection for each number of likes and issue multiple requests to the corresponding subcollections and merge the results.
- Limit the number of likes to 10 values (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 8, >8) and use the `array-contains-any` operator to combine up to 10 array-contains clauses on the field with a logical `OR`. Or limit to 7 values (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, more than 5)
- Adapt your front-end in order to cope with the Firestore capabilities.